# Filling Kendo grid column menu filter options by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my kendo grid, whenever i am applying filters from columnMenu, my grid gets reloaded completely with the filtered result. Hence, i also lost my value inside columnMenu filter textbox.

Is there any way to populate/fill columnMenu filter options through javascript if i have the filter string?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem, but it was when I added new object to the data source (new row) and it rendered the whole grid and I lost textboxes values.
I overcame this problem by adding an event listener on the textboxes when changed and changing the field in the object so when it render the grid again it will set the current value in the textbox.
I'm not sure if it the best solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code of it so that i can study and try to implement the same in my case.